# Hierarchical (nested) XML to csv

Tags: r, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have a large XML-File (1GB and growing in the future) that I need to turn into CSV.
With a smaller file I managed to do so. With the original file it takes hours, which should not be so. Do you have an idea how to speed up the whole process?

My data (only an excerp):

```
<dataExtractBurWeb xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="BurWebExtract-1-8-0.xsd" version="1.8.0">
<dataExtractInfo>
<message></message>
<userId>235235X</userId>
<scope>
<scopeCanton>
<cantonAbbreviation>ZI</cantonAbbreviation>
</scopeCanton>
</scope>
<containsCensus>true</containsCensus>
<containsPerson>false</containsPerson>
<fullExtract>
<dateTime>1999-10-12T02:00:53</dateTime>
</fullExtract>
</dataExtractInfo>
<enterpriseUnits>
<enterpriseUnit><enterpriseUnitOid>1111111</enterpriseUnitOid><enterpriseUnitId>1111112</enterpriseUnitId><adminStatus>5</adminStatus><cantonAbbreviation>ZI</cantonAbbreviation><capitalAmount xsi:nil="true"/><census><date xsi:nil="true"/><employedTotal xsi:nil="true"/><fteFemale xsi:nil="true"/><fteMale xsi:nil="true"/><fteTotal xsi:nil="true"/><fullFemale xsi:nil="true"/><fullMale xsi:nil="true"/><method>5</method><part1Female xsi:nil="true"/><part1Male xsi:nil="true"/><part2Female xsi:nil="true"/><part2Male xsi:nil="true"/><part3Female xsi:nil="true"/><part3Male xsi:nil="true"/><source xsi:nil="true"/><totalFemale xsi:nil="true"/><totalMale xsi:nil="true"/></census><countryIdISO2>DE</countryIdISO2><enterpriseUnitClassification><enterpriseUnitKind>7</enterpriseUnitKind><enterpriseUnitType>F9</enterpriseUnitType><instituteSector>W14</instituteSector><legalForm>04</legalForm><noga2008>453466</noga2008></enterpriseUnitClassification><groupProfiling/><groupVatCustom/><lastChangeDate>1999-02-01T17:18:26</lastChangeDate><latestYearAsImporter xsi:nil="true"/><latestYearAsExporter xsi:nil="true"/><legalId/><legalName>Siuower Schnefls</legalName><municipalityId>3698</municipalityId><name>Siuower Schnefls</name><numberOfLocals>0</numberOfLocals><registeredDate>1988-01-01T00:00:00</registeredDate><sizeClass>0</sizeClass><sourceCreationCd>34</sourceCreationCd><sourceModificationCd>40</sourceModificationCd><statisticalStatus>0</statisticalStatus><enterpriseUnitStatus>3</enterpriseUnitStatus><uid><uidOrganisationId>36987425</uidOrganisationId><uidOrganisationIdCategorie>CHV</uidOrganisationIdCategorie></uid><uidStatus>7</uidStatus><wwwAddress xsi:nil="true"/></enterpriseUnit></enterpriseUnits><enterpriseGroups>
<enterpriseUnit><enterpriseUnitOid>1226654</enterpriseUnitOid><enterpriseUnitId>8746455</enterpriseUnitId><adminStatus>5</adminStatus><cantonAbbreviation>RI</cantonAbbreviation><capitalAmount xsi:nil="true"/><census><date xsi:nil="true"/><employedTotal xsi:nil="true"/><fteFemale xsi:nil="true"/><fteMale xsi:nil="true"/><fteTotal xsi:nil="true"/><fullFemale xsi:nil="true"/><fullMale xsi:nil="true"/><method>
<enterpriseUnit><enterpriseUnitOid>3516589</enterpriseUnitOid><enterpriseUnitId>5465466</enterpriseUnitId><adminStatus>5</adminStatus><cantonAbbreviation>ER</cantonAbbreviation><capitalAmount xsi:nil="true"/><census><date xsi:nil="true"/><employedTotal xsi:nil="true"/><fteFemale xsi:nil="true"/><fteMale xsi:nil="true"/><fteTotal xsi:nil="true"/><fullFemale xsi:nil="true"/><fullMale xsi:nil="true"/><method>
<enterpriseGroup><childEnterpriseUnitOid>55669841</childEnterpriseUnitOid><fatherEnterpriseUnitOid>8789852</fatherEnterpriseUnitOid><lastChangeDate>1999-04-10T09:13:56</lastChangeDate><registeredDate>1999-04-10T09:13:56</registeredDate><sourceCreationCd>105</sourceCreationCd><sourceModificationCd>90</sourceModificationCd><enterpriseGroupStatus>7</enterpriseGroupStatus></enterpriseGroup></enterpriseGroups><localUnits>
<enterpriseGroup><childEnterpriseUnitOid>55669841</childEnterpriseUnitOid><fatherEnterpriseUnitOid>8789852</fatherEnterpriseUnitOid><lastChangeDate>1999-04-10T09:13:56</lastChangeDate><registeredDate>1999-04-10T09:13:56</registeredDate><sourceCreationCd>105</sourceCreationCd><sourceModificationCd>90</sourceModificationCd><enterpriseGroupStatus>7</enterpriseGroupStatus></enterpriseGroup></enterpriseGroups><localUnits>
<enterpriseGroup><childEnterpriseUnitOid>55669841</childEnterpriseUnitOid><fatherEnterpriseUnitOid>8789852</fatherEnterpriseUnitOid><lastChangeDate>1999-04-10T09:13:56</lastChangeDate><registeredDate>1999-04-10T09:13:56</registeredDate><sourceCreationCd>105</sourceCreationCd><sourceModificationCd>90</sourceModificationCd><enterpriseGroupStatus>7</enterpriseGroupStatus></enterpriseGroup></enterpriseGroups><localUnits>
<localUnit><localUnitOid>9981464</localUnitOid><localUnitId>V6686463</localUnitId><addressLine1 xsi:nil="true"/><adminStatus>6</adminStatus><cantonAbbreviation>ZI</cantonAbbreviation><census><date xsi:nil="true"/><employedTotal xsi:nil="true"/><fteFemale xsi:nil="true"/><fteMale xsi:nil="true"/><fteTotal xsi:nil="true"/><fullFemale xsi:nil="true"/><fullMale xsi:nil="true"/><method xsi:nil="true"/><part1Female xsi:nil="true"/><part1Male xsi:nil="true"/><part2Female xsi:nil="true"/><part2Male xsi:nil="true"/><part3Female xsi:nil="true"/><part3Male xsi:nil="true"/><source>90</source><totalFemale xsi:nil="true"/><totalMale xsi:nil="true"/></census><cessationReason>7</cessationReason><countryIdISO2>DE</countryIdISO2><creationDateCantonalRegister xsi:nil="true"/><egidId xsi:nil="true"/><ehraId xsi:nil="true"/><emailAddress xsi:nil="true"/><enterpriseUnitId>6554441</enterpriseUnitId><enterpriseUnitOid>985235</enterpriseUnitOid><estrId xsi:nil="true"/><fatherLocalUnitId xsi:nil="true"/><fatherLocalUnitOid xsi:nil="true"/><foreignZipCode xsi:nil="true"/><houseNumber xsi:nil="true"/><language>5</language><lastChangeDate>1999-12-01T09:28:18</lastChangeDate><latestYearAsApprenticeTrainer xsi:nil="true"/><legalDeletionDate xsi:nil="true"/><legalId/><legalName>Siuower Schnefls</legalName><legalRegistrationDate xsi:nil="true"/><localUnitClassification><legalForm>05</legalForm><localUnitKind>3</localUnitKind><localUnitType>R64</localUnitType><noga2008>646464</noga2008><secondaryNogaCodes xsi:nil="true"/></localUnitClassification><localUnitStatus>3</localUnitStatus><localUnitStatusDate>1989-09-06T00:00:00</localUnitStatusDate><lv95ECoordinate xsi:nil="true"/><lv95NCoordinate xsi:nil="true"/><mainPostalAddress>true</mainPostalAddress><municipalityId>3292</municipalityId><name>Siuower Schnefls</name><nameBusiness xsi:nil="true"/><personId xsi:nil="true"/><phoneNumber xsi:nil="true"/><postOfficeBox xsi:nil="true"/><postOfficeBoxSwissZipCode xsi:nil="true"/><postOfficeBoxSwissZipCodeAddOn xsi:nil="true"/><postOfficeBoxTown xsi:nil="true"/><primarySectorData><agrarKindCd xsi:nil="true"/><cantonUnitNumber xsi:nil="true"/><tvdNumber xsi:nil="true"/></primarySectorData><registeredDate>1988-01-01T00:00:00</registeredDate><seasonActivity>0</seasonActivity><seco><industrialEnterpriseLegalBasisCd xsi:nil="true"/><industrialEnterpriseOperationEndDate xsi:nil="true"/><industrialEnterpriseOperationStartDate xsi:nil="true"/><isConstructionSite>false</isConstructionSite><isFederalEnterprise>false</isFederalEnterprise><isIndustrialEnterprise>false</isIndustrialEnterprise><isPlanAssist>false</isPlanAssist><isSubmittedPlanApproval>false</isSubmittedPlanApproval><isUsedInTacho>false</isUsedInTacho><suvaNumber xsi:nil="true"/></seco><sizeClass xsi:nil="true"/><sourceCreationCd>30</sourceCreationCd><sourceModificationCd>0</sourceModificationCd><statisticalStatus xsi:nil="true"/><street xsi:nil="true"/><swissZipCode>8896</swissZipCode><swissZipCodeAddOn>0</swissZipCodeAddOn><town>Ziosdef</town><transferNewDate xsi:nil="true"/><transferNewEnterpriseUnitId xsi:nil="true"/><transferNewLocalUnitId xsi:nil="true"/><transferNewLocalUnitOid xsi:nil="true"/><transferOldDate xsi:nil="true"/><transferOldEnterpriseUnitId xsi:nil="true"/><transferOldLocalUnitId xsi:nil="true"/><transferOldLocalUnitOid xsi:nil="true"/><uid><uidOrganisationId>546746746</uidOrganisationId><uidOrganisationIdCategorie>CHE</uidOrganisationIdCategorie></uid><uidMainUnit><uidOrganisationId>545567656</uidOrganisationId><uidOrganisationIdCategorie>CHE</uidOrganisationIdCategorie></uidMainUnit><uidStatus>7</uidStatus><unitType>MainLegalUnit</unitType><wwwAddress xsi:nil="true"/></localUnit>
</localUnits>
<dataExtractStatistics>
<enterpriseUnitCount>116970</enterpriseUnitCount>
<enterpriseGroupCount>269</enterpriseGroupCount>
<localUnitCount>229331</localUnitCount>
<processingDateTimeStart>2021-10-12T07:10:22</processingDateTimeStart>
<processingDateTimeEnd>2021-10-12T07:12:35</processingDateTimeEnd>
<duration>00:02:12.8549543</duration></dataExtractStatistics></dataExtractBurWeb>
```

My code so far:

```
library(XML)
library(methods)
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
library(xslt)
library(lubridate)

rm(list=ls())

#########################################################
# Konstanten
#########################################################

k.Datum <- today()

#########################################################
# Datei einlesen
#########################################################

doc <- read_xml("P:/2_Statistikproduktion/BUR/Bezogene Daten/BurWeb2-FullExtract-20211012-071022 - Kopie2.xml")


#########################################################
# Enterprise Unit
#########################################################

# alle Pfade ausschreiben (Kinder und Enkel)
names1 <- xml_path(xml_find_all(doc, ".//enterpriseUnit/*"))
names2 <- xml_path(xml_find_all(doc, ".//enterpriseUnit/*/*"))

# den string zu einem Dataframe umwandeln. Danach muss geschaut werden, dass alle Variablensets gleich lauten (jeder Eintrag hat eine andere Laufnummer)
df.names1 <- as.data.frame(names1)
df.names1 <- as.data.frame(gsub(".*]",".//enterpriseUnit",df.names1$names1))
df.names1 <- unique(df.names1)
names(df.names1)[1] <- "V1"

df.names2 <- as.data.frame(names2)
df.names2 <- as.data.frame(gsub(".*]",".//enterpriseUnit",df.names2$names2))
df.names2 <- unique(df.names2)
names(df.names2)[1] <- "V1"

# Gesamte Variablenliste erstellen
df.names_total <- rbind(df.names1, df.names2)

# Variablenliste als Vektor speichern
v.vector_names <- unlist(as.vector(df.names_total))

# Alle Werte auslesen und zusammenführen.
enterpriseUnit <- do.call(cbind, 
                          lapply(v.vector_names, function(xpath) xml_text(xml_find_all(doc, xpath))))

# Dataframe generieren
df.enterpriseUnit <- as.data.frame(enterpriseUnit)

# Die Variablennamen sind noch nichtssagend. Diese umgenennen mit Hilfe des vorher erstellen Vektors.
df.names_total <- as.data.frame(gsub(".*/","",df.names_total$V1))
v.vector_names_col <- unlist(as.vector(df.names_total))
names(df.enterpriseUnit) <- v.vector_names_col

# Speichern
write.csv(df.enterpriseUnit, paste0("Z:/test/EntUnits_roh_",k.Datum,".csv"))


#########################################################
# Enterprise Group
#########################################################

# alle Pfade ausschreiben (Kinder und Enkel)
names1 <- xml_path(xml_find_all(doc, ".//enterpriseGroup/*"))
names2 <- xml_path(xml_find_all(doc, ".//enterpriseGroup/*/*"))

# den string zu einem Dataframe umwandeln. Danach muss geschaut werden, dass alle Variablensets gleich lauten (jeder Eintrag hat eine andere Laufnummer)
df.names1 <- as.data.frame(names1)
df.names1 <- as.data.frame(gsub(".*]",".//enterpriseGroup",df.names1$names1))
df.names1 <- unique(df.names1)
names(df.names1)[1] <- "V1"

df.names2 <- as.data.frame(names2)
df.names2 <- as.data.frame(gsub(".*]",".//enterpriseGroup",df.names2$names2))
df.names2 <- unique(df.names2)
names(df.names2)[1] <- "V1"

# Gesamte Variablenliste erstellen
df.names_total <- rbind(df.names1, df.names2)

# Variablenliste als Vektor speichern
v.vector_names <- unlist(as.vector(df.names_total))

# Alle Werte auslesen und zusammenführen.
enterpriseGroups <- do.call(cbind, 
                          lapply(v.vector_names, function(xpath) xml_text(xml_find_all(doc, xpath))))

# Dataframe generieren
df.enterpriseGroups <- as.data.frame(enterpriseGroups)

# Die Variablennamen sind noch nichtssagend. Diese umgenennen mit Hilfe des vorher erstellen Vektors.
df.names_total <- as.data.frame(gsub(".*/","",df.names_total$V1))
v.vector_names_col <- unlist(as.vector(df.names_total))
names(df.enterpriseGroups) <- v.vector_names_col

# Speichern
write.csv(df.enterpriseGroups paste0("Z:/test/EntGroups_roh_",k.Datum,".csv"))


#########################################################
# Local Unit
#########################################################

# alle Pfade ausschreiben (Kinder und Enkel)
names1 <- xml_path(xml_find_all(doc, ".//localUnit/*"))
names2 <- xml_path(xml_find_all(doc, ".//localUnit/*/*"))

# den string zu einem Dataframe umwandeln. Danach muss geschaut werden, dass alle Variablensets gleich lauten (jeder Eintrag hat eine andere Laufnummer)
df.names1 <- as.data.frame(names1)
df.names1 <- as.data.frame(gsub(".*]",".//localUnit",df.names1$names1))
df.names1 <- unique(df.names1)
names(df.names1)[1] <- "V1"

df.names2 <- as.data.frame(names2)
df.names2 <- as.data.frame(gsub(".*]",".//localUnit",df.names2$names2))
df.names2 <- unique(df.names2)
names(df.names2)[1] <- "V1"

# Gesamte Variablenliste erstellen
df.names_total <- rbind(df.names1, df.names2)

# Variablenliste als Vektor speichern
v.vector_names <- unlist(as.vector(df.names_total))

# Alle Werte auslesen und zusammenführen.
localUnit <- do.call(cbind, 
                          lapply(v.vector_names, function(xpath) xml_text(xml_find_all(doc, xpath))))

# Dataframe generieren
df.localUnit <- as.data.frame(localUnit)

# Die Variablennamen sind noch nichtssagend. Diese umgenennen mit Hilfe des vorher erstellen Vektors.
df.names_total <- as.data.frame(gsub(".*/","",df.names_total$V1))
v.vector_names_col <- unlist(as.vector(df.names_total))
names(df.localUnit) <- v.vector_names_col

# Speichern
write.csv(df.localUnit paste0("Z:/test/localUnit_roh_",k.Datum,".csv"))
```

I also tried with XSLT, but I have failed miserably.

I appreciate every hint. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Anja, you have to write a recurrent function which does the job!

Comment: Thanks sveer. I'll have a try. Do I need to put the whole code in a function?

Comment: yes, you create one function that gets all the relevant information from one set into a data.frame or list. another function that calls the same function recursively over the sets and binds the rows of data.frame / append to the list set by set. call the second function in the same function.